# How to use gojs extensions in angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, gojs

How do I actually use gojs extensions in my Angular 4 project?
gojs has been added to the project and I see the extensions in the gojs node modules.

I have the following inside my component:

```
import * as go from 'gojs';
import TableLayout from '../../node_modules/gojs/extensionsTS/TableLayout'; 

ngOnInit() {
    new TableLayout()
}
```

but I'm getting the following build errors:

```
ERROR in node_modules/gojs/extensionsTS/TableLayout.ts(414,8):
        error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'child' must be of type 'Part', but here has type 'any'.
    node_modules/gojs/extensionsTS/TableLayout.ts(445,8):
        error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'child' must be of type 'Part', but here has type 'any'.
    node_modules/gojs/extensionsTS/TableLayout.ts(542,9):
        error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'child' must be of type 'Part', but here has type 'any'.
    src/app/app.component.ts(3,8):
        error TS1192: Module '"D:/projects/gojs-app1/node_modules/gojs/extensionsTS/TableLayout"' has no default export.
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm trying to import an extension with Angular 7 but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **npm**

try to do this:

`npm install gojs -g --save`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

> import { BalloonLink } from 'gojs/extensions/BalloonLink.js';

Be aware that there are both **/extensions** and **/extensionsTS** paths.

**Edit**

Also you can copy and paste from node_modules of gojs lib into your local folders and then import as a component. This worked for me.